# Read full file path from text file and return file name with extension

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a text file filter which filters a particular word from the text using a Windows [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

My code:

```
findstr ".txt" filename.txt > name.txt
```

filename.txt:

```
C:\Users\PhilipRamya\Desktop\fruits.txt
```

Expected output in `name.txt`

```
fruits.txt
```

Actual output in `name.txt`

```
C:\Users\PhilipRamya\Desktop\fruits.txt
```

Comment: Let me see if I've got this straight: you've got a data file that contains text files with their full paths in it and you're using `findstr` to find lines that contain the string `.txt` and you're wondering why `findstr` is returning the entire line instead of just the filename?

Comment: Yes exactly you got my point. @SomethingDark

Comment: Why are you expecting only the filename to be returned? `find` and `findstr` (and `grep` if you were using Linux`) return the entire line that a search string is found on.

Comment: i am looking only for the file name to input it in another filter batch program. Thats why i need only that `filename.txt` . And i am not using linux here. I need the solution and fix in windows

Comment: I was just trying to convey that returning the entire line is the default behavior :)

Comment: Your expected may be wanted, but is certainly not expected. You could run it through a `For` loop, and use the metavariable modifiers, to output your required filename and extension. `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Find ".txt"^<"filename.txt"')Do @Echo(%%~nxA)>>"name.txt"`. You could also use `FindStr` similarly, with perhaps, `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /L ".txt" "filename.txt"')Do @Echo(%%~nxA)>>"name.txt"`. In both cases, you may also wish to consider using `/I`, and if choosing `FindStr`, you may also want to consider including `/E`, or using its regex mode with an escaped `.` and `$`.

Comment: `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /L ".txt" "filename.txt"')Do @Echo(%%~nxA>>"name.txt"` Thanks a lot this works :) @Compo

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use `findstr.exe` or `find.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` in this case to first filter the list of full qualified file names in list file `filename.txt` before processing the filtered file names further with command **FOR**. It is better in my point of view to directly process the list file with **FOR**.

```
@echo off
(for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("filename.txt") do if /I "%%~xI" == ".txt" echo %%~nxI)>name.txt
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`